# Sucessive stimuli effect on auditive perception

Tags: r

My experiment is about auditive perception, and consists of playing sound at A Random locations (1-6), B Different frequencies (1-6), C is a Choice location (1-6 proposed choices).

Participants were asked to report their perception of the location of the sound. For each participant, a series of about 760 successive combinations of stimuli were played.

The research problem is about whether humans perceive sound according to their real location OR frequency bias (low frequency judged as coming from the low region and vice versa).

Then we test as `(DV) Decision_choice ~ and (ID) Frequency + Location`

The overall participants analyses was:

```
anova(lm(Choice ~ Frequency+ Location,pre_post_part),test="Chisq")
Response: Choice
             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Frequency     1    54.4  54.400 24.5263 7.433e-07 ***
Location       1     1.0   1.011  0.4556    0.4997    
Residuals 11659 25859.9   2.218
```

It appears that Frequency has a significant effect but not location.

Now I want to explore whether there is any effect of successive playing of sounds. Some reported motivation as: "*This sound seems lower than the last one that I've judged as coming from 3, so I'll reduce my judgement according to my previous judgement*".

If there is an effect of prior judgement with its respective significant Independent Variable, maybe I should reintroduce and retest the previous Location also.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this, except for some descriptive statistics and graphs as follow; X= difference frequency t vs t-1 and Y =difference choice t vs t-1:

[image]

This reports accurately if the combination is not changed. I note also that variance in choice seems to be restricted. But I cannot go further than that.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions for statistical methods I can use?

Here is some data :

```
  data=structure(list(Id = c("2", "4", "5", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "32", "33", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"40", "41", "43", "44", "45", "47", "50", "52", "53", "54", "57", 
"59", "60", "61", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "70", "72", 
"73", "74", "75", "76", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "85", 
"86", "87", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "97", "98", "99", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "114", "116", "117", "121", "122", "123", 
"124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", 
"133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", 
"142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", 
"151", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "160", "161", "162", 
"163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "172", 
"173", "175", "176", "177", "179", "183", "184", "187", "188", 
"189", "190", "191", "193", "194", "195", "197", "198", "200", 
"201", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "211", 
"212", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", 
"222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", 
"231", "232", "235", "237", "239", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "255", 
"256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", "264", 
"265", "266", "267", "268", "270", "271", "272", "273", "274", 
"275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "281", "282", "284", "285", 
"286", "288", "289", "290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", 
"296", "297", "298", "299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "305", 
"306", "307", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", 
"316", "318", "319", "320", "321", "323", "324", "325", "327", 
"328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "335", "336", "338", 
"339", "340", "341", "342", "345", "346", "348", "352", "353", 
"354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", "362", 
"363", "366", "368", "369", "370", "371", "373", "374", "375", 
"376", "377", "378", "379", "380", "381", "382", "383", "385", 
"386", "387", "388", "389", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", 
"396", "397", "398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", 
"405", "407", "408", "409", "411", "412", "413", "414", "416", 
"417", "418", "420", "421", "422", "424", "425", "426", "427", 
"428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", "435", "436", "438", 
"439", "441", "442", "443", "445", "446", "447", "449", "450", 
"451", "452", "453", "455", "456", "457", "459", "460", "461", 
"462", "463", "464", "465", "467", "468", "469", "470", "472", 
"473", "474", "475", "476", "477", "479", "480", "482", "483", 
"484", "486", "487", "488", "489", "490", "491", "492", "493", 
"495", "496", "497", "498", "499", "500", "501", "502", "503", 
"504", "505", "506", "507", "508", "509", "510", "514", "515", 
"517", "518", "520", "521", "522", "523", "524", "525", "526", 
"527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", "533", "534", "535", 
"536", "538", "539", "540", "541", "542", "543", "544", "545", 
"546", "547", "548", "549", "550", "551", "552", "553", "554", 
"555", "556", "557", "558", "559", "561", "562", "564", "566", 
"567", "568", "569", "570", "571", "573", "574", "575", "576", 
"577", "579", "580", "581", "582", "583", "584", "585", "586", 
"587", "588", "589", "590", "591", "592", "593", "594", "596", 
"598", "599", "600", "601", "602", "603", "604", "605", "606", 
"607", "608", "609", "610", "611", "612", "613", "614", "615", 
"616", "619", "620", "621", "622", "623", "624", "625", "627", 
"628", "629", "630", "631", "632", "633", "634", "635", "636", 
"637", "638", "640", "641", "643", "644", "646", "647", "648", 
"649", "651", "652", "653", "654", "655", "657", "658", "659", 
"660", "661", "662", "663", "665", "667", "668", "669", "670", 
"671", "673", "674", "675", "676", "678", "679", "682", "683", 
"685", "686", "687", "688", "689", "690", "691", "692", "693", 
"694", "697", "698", "699", "700", "701", "702", "703", "705", 
"706", "707", "708", "709", "710", "711", "712", "713", "714", 
"715", "716", "717", "718", "719", "720", "721", "722", "723", 
"724", "725", "726", "727", "728", "729", "730", "731", "734", 
"735", "736", "737", "738", "739", "740", "743", "744", "745", 
"746", "747", "748", "749", "750", "751", "752", "755", "756", 
"757", "760", "761", "762", "763", "764", "765", "768", "769", 
"770", "771", "772", "773", "774", "775", "776", "777", "778", 
"779", "781", "783", "785", "786", "1", "2", "4", "5", "7", "8", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "49", "50", "52", "53", "54", "57", "59", "60", "61", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "72", "73", "74", "75", 
"76", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "85", "86", "87", "90", 
"91", "92"), Location = c(1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Frequency = c(5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
6L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Choice = c(5L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L), Participant = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", 
"Location", "Frequency", "Choice", "Participant"), row.names = c(NA, 
-720L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), vars = "Participant", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:645, 646:719), group_sizes = c(646L, 
74L), biggest_group_size = 646L, labels = structure(list(Participant = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Participant", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Participant"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these "successive stimuli" effects, consider a model that includes an autoregressive component.  A natural contender for your data would be a multi-level model that includes an AR1 term.  [Paul Bliese's book](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Bliese_Multilevel.pdf) is a free introduction to this kind of modeling with R code.

Your experiment seems to involve *crossed* rather than *nested* random effects.  For this situation, you can find some good background theory in a classic article by [Baayen and colleagues (2008)](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~larget/Stat998/Fall2015/BaayenDavidsonBates-2008.pdf).